# Find the Variable with biggest int value

Tags: java

I am developing a Java application.

I have five int variables. They may contain different int values. I want to check which variable is the biggest. Depending on that variable, I have to execute different method.

```
int intHx;
int intEx;
int intRx;
int intMx;
int intIx;
```

How can I find the variable with the highest value?

PS: To Clarify
I want to pick the variable with highest value, not the value that variable contain. This is not related to sorting values, but executing different method.

Comment: Have you ever heard of sorting?

Comment: You can simply compare them one by one. You don't have to sort them, since you only care about finding the largest one.

Comment: You question is clear and well written, but you left out the part that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has not put in any effort.

Comment: you can use Math.max().See this example http://ideone.com/sfrIPh

Comment: Show us your effort to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This enum is optional, but helps with code clarity:

```
enum Field {
    INT_HX,
    INT_EX,
    INT_RX,
    INT_MX,
    INT_IX
}
```

Then test the values:

```
Field largestField = Field.INT_HX;
int largestValue = intHx;
if(intEx > largestValue) {
    largestField = Field.INT_EX;
    largestValue = intEx;
}
if(intRx > largestValue) {
    largestField = Field.INT_RX;
    largestValue = intRx;
}
if(intMx > largestValue) {
    largestField = Field.INT_MX;
    largestValue = intMx;
}
if(intIx > largestValue) {
    largestValue = intIx;
}
switch(largestField) {
    case INT_HX:
        // call the intHx related method
    break;
    case INT_EX:
        // call the intEx related method
    break;
    case INT_RX:
        // call the intRx related method
    break;
    case INT_MX:
        // call the intMx related method
    break;
    case INT_IX:
        // call the intIx related method
    break;
}
```

Comment: I am again very much grateful to you for this answer as it  solved my issue with the best possible algorithm. It was very useful. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

```
Field largestField;
if (num1>num2)
{
   largestField = Field.num1;
}
else
{
   largestField = Field.num2; 
}
if (largest < num3)
{
   largestField = Field.num3;
}
if (largest < num4)
{
   largestField = Field.num4;
}
if (largest < num5)
{
   largestField = Field.num5;
}
```

At the end the value inside largest will be the largest among 5.

Comment: This doesn't help OP to call the appropriate method based on which variable had the largest value.

Comment: I want to pick the variable, not the value.

Comment: changed the solution accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Required JDK 8 )

```
 private int getMax(int... numbers){
    OptionalInt max = Arrays.stream(numbers).max();
    return max.getAsInt();
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't help OP to call the appropriate method based on which variable had the largest value.